# Unexplained behavior in Safari with negative array indices

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

**Edit**: Simpler repro case; the following code:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var a=[10,20,30,40], i=-1;
  a[-1] = 42;
  while (i<10000) a[i++];
  console.log(a[-1],a[4294967295]);
},100);
```

…produces the output:

```
     42 undefined
     undefined 42
     42 undefined
37x  undefined 42
     42 undefined
     undefined 42
     42 undefined
41x  undefined 42
     42 undefined
     undefined 42
     42 undefined
```

### Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Fjwsg/

---

(Original question follows)

Given the following code (or [code like it (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/TzCm9/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>-1 Array Index</title></head><body>
  <label>p: <input id="p" size="3"></label>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var p = document.getElementById('p');
  p.onkeyup = function(){
    var a = "10 20 30 40".split(/\s+/);
    foo(a, p.value*1);
  }

  function foo(a,p){
    var count=a.length, i=0, x;
    if (p) a[i=-1]=p;
    while (i<10000) x = a[i++ % count];
    console.dir(a);
  }
  </script>
</body></html>
```

I see the following in the Developer Console when I focus the "p" input and type <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>:
[image: Array has index of -1 on first pass, index of 4294967295 on third pass]

Once I see the index of `4294967295` (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) show up, things sometimes begin to "go bad": sometimes the Developer Tools automatically close, sometimes all Safari tabs freeze and require a relaunch to recover.

Oddly, I can't repro this if I remove the (largely useless in this case) while loop. And I can't repro this on Chrome or Firefox.

Can anyone shed any light on what could possibly be at the root of this problem?

*This is occurring with Safari 5.1.7 on OS X 10.7.4*

Comment: I'm still looking this over but the while loop doesn't actually do "nothing", it increments the `i` variable.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/TzCm9/) in Safari 5.1.4 on a Windows 7 machine. When I type `1` I get length 4, backspace I get length 4, and when I type `2` I get length 4. It's also setting `a[-1]` to equal 1 and then 2 on the appropriate keypresses, which is kind of impossible. I'm stumped.

Comment: In Safari 5.1.6 OS 10.7.4 I get the weird index, but nothing freezes.

Comment: Do you mean `if (p) a[i=-1]=p;` or `if (p) a[i -= 1]=p;`.

Comment: If you actually intend to use a negative index, change the index to strings and use an object as the storage rather than array.

Comment: @Andrew The former; I have an array that I loop through, but on the first pass just once I needed to inject one extra value. I can do it another way, and will, but that's what led to this.

Comment: @Phrogz I can't remember where I read this, but Douglas Crockford said that JavaScript's `Array` is actually just a regular `Object` with an extra `length` property, which is always 1 greater than the largest numeric index in the object, and that JS uses type coercion to change the numeric index to a string during lookups and insertions. There's obviously a bit more happening under the hood, but it means you don't lose much by keeping what you have now and going to a `{}` instead of a `[]`. Anyway, in other languages you can't use neg. indexes because the index is a pointer to the heap.

Comment: @Andrew that sounds about right, the ecma spec says that the index cannot be 2^32-1 (also in my answer) because that value is reserved for the `.length` property before it overflows.

Comment: @Andrew Note that `a=[]; a[1]="foo"; a["2"]="bar"; a["1"]=="foo" && a[2]=="bar" // true`. All JavaScript properties are equivalent to strings internally--even array indices--so _"chang[ing] the index to strings"_ would not effect the result.

Comment: @Jack That's the most interesting thing about JS I've read in a long while. It makes sense, but I honestly can't help feeling like that's just a cheap work-around. It's hard to believe that's in an RFC.

Comment: @Phrogz With all the optimization that's gone into modern JS engines, I'd be reluctant to say that there'd be no difference at all in string-based indexes vs. numerical indexes. In strongly typed languages, numeric indexes are typically *much* faster than hashes. On the other hand, an added step (for number-to-string coercion) will barely but measurably slow things down. I haven't a clue how it would shake down at the end, but it would be interesting to test which is faster in various browsers.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there is [a performance difference](http://jsperf.com/string-vs-integer-array-indices) for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in JavaScriptCore to me. Perhaps `foo` is being JITted when it's called the second time and the JITted code introduces the bug.

I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://webkit.org/new-bug) against JavaScriptCore and attaching your test case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and possible explanation. I've filed this as [bug #86733](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86733).

Answer (score 3):

Using negative indices may result in undefined behaviour.

According to the [ECMAScript documentation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4), a particular value `p` can only be an array index if and only if:

```
(p >>> 0 === p) && (p >>> 0 !== Math.pow(2, 32) - 1)
```

In your case:

```
# -1 >>> 0
4294967295
# Math.pow(2, 32) - 1
4294967295
```

**edit**

If `p` fails above test, it should be treated as a regular object property like `a.foo` or `a['foo']`. That said, as it turns out, setting the negative index with a string cast works around the issue.

```
a['' + (i =-1)] = p
```

Conclusion: browser bug

Comment: I appreciate your link, but I think the nomenclature used by the specification is confusing you. Array--like all objects in JavaScript--can have any number of arbitrary properties added to them at runtime. The specification simply constrains which properties are considered an "Array Index" for the purposes of auto-updating the `length` property. It is perfectly valid to add a property `foo` or `lastSeen` or `"OMG!"` to an array.

Comment: @Phrogz I'm aware that Array objects can be extended at runtime, so I guess the second part of my answer could be improved ... the first part is still valid though; wondering why this got downvoted =/

Comment: I downvoted it. The first part of your answer is correct (citing specs accurately) but a red herring. Setting a property named `"-1"` is no more "naughty" than setting a property named `"yo' momma"`: both are acceptable per the specs, and simply will not be considered an "array index" (and all that entails). (And your first statement is sort of begging the question: other than this bug on what browser on what platform, can you cite any other cases where negative indices result in "unexpected behavior"?)

Comment: @Phrogz there's a difference between a["-1"] and a[-1] though. Are you saying that the JavaScript engine should convert the invalid index to a string, thereby avoiding the problem you were seeing?

Comment: @Phrogz you're right about the 'results in unexpected behaviour' .. I've updated that; sorry, English is not my first language, so what I think and write are not always the same :)

Comment: `a[-1]="foo"; a["-1"]=="foo"; a["-2"]="bar"; a[-.2e1]=="bar"`

Comment: `var a = [1, 2, 3]; a[-1] = 'wat'; a.length == 3; for (var x in a) { console.log(a[x]); // 1, 2, 3, wat` ... it's just better avoided imho. btw, did you try the same script but cast the -1 to string?

Comment: I did, and found that setting the index as a string `a["-1"] = …` does, in fact, work around this bug (!)

Comment: @phrogz thanks for the verification. Answer updated to reflect this.